# Rails association attributes access from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an rails 5 API only rails app with a many to many relationship as follows:

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :managements, inverse_of: :business, autosave: true
  has_many :managers, through: :managements, source: :user, autosave: true
end

class Management < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :business
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :business }
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :managements
  has_many :businesses, through: :managements
end
```

within the Business class I have the following method which I want to use to set the owner on the Management join table.

```
def owner=(user)
    userAsManager = managements.find_by(user_id: user.id)
    unless userAsManager
      managers << user
      self.save
      userAsManager = managements.find_by(user_id: user.id)
    end
    if userAsManager && !userAsManager.owner
      if owner
        self.managements_attributes = [
          { id: managements.find_by(user_id: owner.id).id, owner: false }
        ]
        save
      end
      self.managements_attributes = [ {id: userAsManager.id, owner: true}]
      save
    end
  end
```

The reason for this logic in a setter is to manage all situations where there are no managers, where there is an existing owner etc. What I have found is that in an Rspec test such as:

```
it 'added when the owner is already a manager' do
  business.managers << owner
  business.save
  business.owner = owner
  business.save
  expect(Business.first.owner).to eq owner
  expect(Business.first.managers[0]).to eq owner
end
```

I have to keep saving the model otherwise when I access self within the `owner=(user)` method the associated models are not available. e.g. within the test having set `owner` as a `business.managers` if the `business` is not saved, then on setting the owner to be an owner of the business `business.owner = owner` when entering the `owner=(user)` method `self.managers` is an empty object.

Why is this and is there a way I can do updates within the model and then save it once complete within the test?

TBH I am not that happy with a lot of this code, I don't really understand why I need self on `self.managements_attributes`and why I can't just use `managements.find_by(user_id: user.id).owner = true` to set the owner, so if you can point me to some good resources that can explain association use at a deeper lever, that would really help.

Comment: Try adding `inverse_of` to both sides of the associations. In `Business` you have `has_many :managements, inverse_of: :business`. For the associations to be linked you also need the same in the `Management` class: `belongs_to :business, inverse_of: :managements`. Using `inverse_of` should help with accessing unsaved associated objects.

Comment: Two questions: 1) A business can have only one owner or can have more than one? 2) Are you changing the id in the managements table in you code?

Comment: Thanks, @Sharagoz I think that inverse_of is part of the solution, it does help, but I am still unsure how to access the join table object when it hasn't been saved as all ids are nil still. I am trying to read around accepts_nested_attributes_for, but worked out sufficiently yet.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo,  at the moment I only have one owner so I could provide the foreign key on the Business, but this could change and I am more wanting to build understanding than just find a solution. The follow on issue is that all of the ids in managements are nil, so not sure how I access the appropriate managements object. May be accepts_nested_attributes_for, will be the answer to that, but I'm still not sure how I can use that without saving and therefore knowing some ids.

Comment: This was my idea and I think it would be easier. But if this could change, it is better to have the owner in the Management. Ids in management shouldn't be null. Aren't id the primary key? How were they created? Isn't it a serial ( sequence) in the db?

Comment: They will be when saved, but if I try to create the Business, Manager, Managements and set the owner flag on the Management and then save, then until the point of saving it the ids are all nil. It just seems to me that I should be able to call from my controller to set up a business, managers and the owner and then save it.

Comment: They will be when saved, but if I try to create the Business, Manager, Managements and set the owner flag on the Management and then save, then until the point of saving it the ids are all nil. It just seems to me that I should be able to call from my controller to set up a business, managers and the owner and then save it.

Comment: What is the owner (in `if owner`) . It's a method in the Business model? How is it defined?

Comment: It just returns the current owner if one exists (again relying on the management object having been saved): def owner
    if managements.find_by(owner: true)
      managers.find(managements.find_by(owner: true).user_id)
    end
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access in memory objects that havent been saved yet a couple of changes are needed. First, use `inverse_of` on both sides to link the associations.
Example:

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :managements, inverse_of: :business
end

class Management < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :business, inverse_of: :managements
end
```

To look up records that are added to the association but not yet saved to the DB you cant use `find_by` because that method calls the database. Instead you can use `Array#find`. Something like this:

```
def owner=(user)
  management = managements.find { |m| m.user ==  user } || self.managments.new(user: user)
  management.owner ||= management.owner.blank?
end
```

Comment: Thank-you, that is exactly what I was after. One little error which I have corrected. Since I currently have only one owner if there is an existing owner I need to also set any existing owner other than the current one to not be the owner first, but now that I know how to go about finding the user managements record my issues are solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code could be like this. You wrote something about your code not working as it should (so you used attributes). Does this code have the same problem? I added many reloads because of the problem you mentioned in your tests. Maybe they are not needed.

```
def owner=(user)
  #Added reload. Could this solve the problem about empty managements in tests?
  userAsManager = managements.reload.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  unless userAsManager
    managers << user
    userAsManager = managements.reload.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end
  if userAsManager
    #Just for simplicity, remove all other owners and add this one.
    managements.update_all(owner: false)
    userAsManager.update_attributes(owner: true)
    managements.reload
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank-you @pablo I think that the reload will just reload from the database, but if it isn't saved it retrieves nothing.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if you save (in the tests) does this work? At least, it does not use the management_attributes.

Comment: Correct, but the solution that Sharagoz provided is much cleaner and does cater for the situation where a manager is added and then made an owner.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things...

**First, about business.save on tests:**

From Rails guide, on ["Controlling Caching"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching):

> *All of the association methods are built around caching, which keeps the result of the most recent query available for further operations.*

So you have to options:

a) in tests intead of `business.save`, you could use `business.reload`

or

b) in your `owner=` method, reload your association before using find_by: `managements.reload`

Here is abit of information regarding read in tests: [In-Memory vs. Database Layer -- .reload](http://www.derrick-mar.com/rails_blog/under_the_hood_posts/ar_reload)

**Second, About `self.managements_attributes`**

> why I can't just use managements.find_by(user_id: user.id).owner = true to set the owner

Because you are not updating the owner in database with that call. Your call is like this:

```
to_update = managements.find_by(user_id: user.id)
to_update.owner = true
```

That changes is not persised in database. To update db you can do this:

```
user_as_manager = managements.find_by(user_id: user.id)
user_as_manager.owner = true
user_as_manager.save # this will persist the owner to the database
```

Which is the same as

```
user_as_manager = managements.find_by(user_id: user.id)
user_as_manager.update(owner: true)
```

Which is the same as

```
managements.find_by(user_id: user.id).update(owner: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to do everything in the model without saving. However thanks for your links and the explanation for reload, that has really helped my understanding here.